# Honoring system mute state with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, audio

Our app is using MediaPlayer to play sound effects. We'd like those not to play when the user has silenced the phone (e.g., set it to vibrate or silent and not plugged in headphones).

By default, it doesn't honor the system state: the sound plays regardless. I can use `AudioManager.getRingerMode()` to stop the sound playing, but (a) it feels like a hack, and (b) it doesn't handle the headphone case -- if I'm listening to music on headphones but have silenced the ringer, I'd like the sound to play.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you'll have to use a combination of logic with `getRingerMode()` and `isWiredHeadsetOn()` to pause or mute the audio accordingly.

NOTE: `isWiredHeadsetOn()` was deprecated for some reason in API 14, but remains the only way to check whether or not headphones are connected. The docs state:

> Use only to check is a headset is connected or not.

[Read about that here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isWiredHeadsetOn%28%29)

So yes, there is a way to do this, though I don't know if it's precisely what you were looking for.

Comment: `isWiredHeadsetOn` is only deprecated for the purpose of checking whether audio is routed to the headset. It's still ok to use it for checking if a headset is connected. An alternative is to listen for `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` broadcasts.

Comment: So hang on...if `isWiredHeadsetOn()` can no longer be relied upon to check whether audio is routed to the headset, then does that mean it could return true and still result in my audio playing via the phone's speaker?